# Using flex 4 to make ribbon based interface

Tags: apache-flex, air, mxml, ribbon

Is it possible to make [ribbon like interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872782.aspx) similar to MS Office suite using Flex 4 for a Adobe AIR desktop application

Comment: How is a Ribbon different from a TabNavigator with buttonBars in it?  I've asked that before, but no one asking for a Ribbon ever provides an answer.

Comment: +1 to Flextras, I've been thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.

Best implementation is done by the Mindomo guys, over here: http://www.mindomo.com/demo.htm

Otherwise you could port ( and opensource and post here off cause :) ) this:
http://silverlightribbon.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Too bad that Mindomo's demo version has the Ribbon disabled. You need to login to see it in action.